Map alternative for rendering faster in JavaScript
There is a list of data coming in from an API, which I am displaying with the help of Map() in my React Application. But the problem here is that the data consists of more than 200 records and all of them are loading one by one. Hence making the load time very high which is not suitable for any website. Please provide any alternative to load the data immediately when the page is opened or maybe a better alternative.
Let me post a sample of my code for better understanding of my problem.
function getEventDetails(){
    const formattedDay = day.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
    const eventsOnDay = eventsCountandDate.find(evt => evt.date === formattedDay);
    
    return eventsOnDay && eventsOnDay.courseCount > 0 ? (
      <div className="eventDetailsBox">
        {eventsOnDay.courses.map((course) => {
          return (
            <div className="force-overflow">
              {course.registrationLink ? ( 
                <p className="eventsDetailsOnBox_text isClickableEvent" onClick={() => RedirectToPage(course.registrationLink)}>{course.courseName}</p>
              ):(
                <p className="eventsDetailsOnBox_text" onClick={() => RedirectToPage(course.registrationLink)}>{course.courseName}</p>
              )}
            </div>
          )
        })}
    </div>
) : null;


This sample doesn't look like to have performance issue. Load 200 records one by one isn't a problem by itself

Consider using the Network panel in Dev Tools to see just how much data is coming in from the API, and the React Dev Tools Profiler to figure out which component is taking so long to render. Also, what is the format method?

@ViniciusKatata basically its a calendar application, say the data what you see in "Microsoft Teams", the data loads up immediately. But in my case everything loads too slow and I can literally see the boxes getting populated one by one which not an ideal cases to load up any data. So hoping my application also functions in that manner..

With the information you told, the issue might be on the server or the way you are requesting it, can you share it with us?
